# How to make Spring Data Elasticsearch serialize aggregation results

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to obtain aggregations from ES using Spring Data Elasticsearch with the following code (in a service):

```
public SearchHits<Document> getDocumentMetadata() {
    Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withAggregations(terms("documents-aggr").field("type.keyword"))
        .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
        .withMaxResults(0)
        .build();

    return elasticsearchOperations.search(query, Document.class);
}
```

In a controller, the code looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("documents")
public SearchHits<Document> getDocumentsMetadata() {
    return documentService.getDocumentMetadata();
}
```

The `Document` class is very simple and looks like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "rtk-documents")
public class Document {

  private List<String> authors;
  private String title;
  private DocumentType type;
}
```

And when I send a request to this endpoint, I get:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-04-26T10:52:28.653+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/documents"
}
```

And the internal exception looks like this:

```
2022-04-26 12:52:28.648 ERROR 277610 --- [io-10210-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.clients.elasticsearch7.ElasticsearchAggregations]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.clients.elasticsearch7.ElasticsearchAggregations and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.SearchHitsImpl["aggregations"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.clients.elasticsearch7.ElasticsearchAggregations and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.SearchHitsImpl["aggregations"])
    at 
    ...
```

Used versions:

- spring-boot-starter-web, spring-data-elasticsearch: 2.6.7

I wonder how to make the controller serialize the answer from ES and send it to a client. I searched for this issue but didn't find any answer that would be related to my problem.

Comment: `SearchHits` was introduced in Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0. The aggregations returned are the classes from the Elasticsearch library. If you want to send this through some rest endpoint, you provide some converter for these classes.

Comment: Thanks @P.J.Meisch for the answer. So I guess I would need to handle it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `ElasticsearchOperations`, you can use the `ElasticsearchClient` to get back an object that implements `JsonpSerializable`.

The you can use the `JsonpUtils` class to serialize as json.

For example -

```java
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient;
import co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpUtils;

...

  final var searchResponse = client.search(request, Object.class); // or use your Document class

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  JsonpUtils.toString(searchResponse, sb);
  log.debug("response: {}", sb);
```